# Error opening connection SQLite on Raspberry pi

Tags: java, sqlite, raspberry-pi

Update: I just check the latest JDBC jar which I use, and it's missing the map /Linux/arm/libsqlitejdbc.so, Would this problem be fixed by downloading this file from somewhere? Can't find it anywhere.

Edit: Problem seems to be this, however I don't know how to fix this.

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error loading native library: /org/sqlite/native/Linux/arm/libsqlitejdbc.so
```

I'm trying to use a SQLite database on my raspberry pi. However I can't get it to work. I get the output posted below. I'm using the JDBC driver. The code works fine on my main computer. I have searched everywhere but can't find a solution. I packed my code into a Jar file if that matters.

Relevant code:

```
     private final String dbLocation = "jdbc:sqlite:" + System.getProperty("user.home") + "/ServerSQLite.db";

    public SQLServer() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("DB location: " + dbLocation);
        Connection connection = null;
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        try {

            // create a database connection
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbLocation);
```

Output:

```
DB location: jdbc:sqlite:/usr/share/tomcat7/ServerSQLite.db
Error opening connection
```

Edit: same problem with hardcoded location which should have both read and write permission:

```
jdbc:sqlite:/home/pi/ServerSQLite.db
Error opening connection
```

Thankful for any help I can get :)

Edit 2: Thought I printed stack trace, but didn't here it is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error opening connection
    ...Lots of exception
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error loading native library: /org/sqlite/native/Linux/arm/libsqlitejdbc.so
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:241)
...
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:175)
    ... 29 more
Error opening connection
```

Problem seems to be Caused by:

```
java.lang.Exception: Error loading native library: /org/sqlite/native/Linux/arm/libsqlitejdbc.so
```

Comment: Why do you have a `try` block with no `catch` or `finally`?

Comment: Because I didn't post the whole code, didn't think it was needed for my question. Added it tho now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download an arm build of SQLite library.
I found only one place where you can get it: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issue/79/compile-for-arm

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit on this? I've tried something along `jar uf sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar org/` with the file at `org/sqlite/native/Linux/arm/libsqlitejdbc.so`but hit a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.NativeDB` when using the updated lib. Which version of sqlite-jdbc are you using? Which steps are you taking?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it looks like the Pi's `$HOME` is set to a read-only system location. This is buggy, but the best workaround is to permit the user to specify a property that will override the entire file name instead of always using the home directory.

Comment: Thank you, changed the location but still gives same error. jdbc:sqlite:/home/pi/ServerSQLite.db
Error opening connection

Comment: Where is that `Error opening connection` coming from, and do you not get any more detailed stack trace?

Comment: Sadly that's all I get as exception. I catch it, but that's all it prints. I know it's the line connection=DriverMa.... which causes the problem. Will double check that it prints the stackTrace.

Comment: Posted trace now in main post. Might have found why it doesn't work now. Seems like I need /org/sqlite/native/Linux/arm/libsqlitejdbc.so file

Comment: I am having this problem, can you please tell me how you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my POM and works fine for me

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you only need the [jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.10.1/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.10.1.jar)

Running on:
    ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.19-18+deb8u4) 2.19
    Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
    Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.