# Where can I get a sqlite-jdbc.jar for ARM (aka my Raspberry Pi)?

Tags: jdbc, sqlite, raspberry-pi

The binaries for Linux, OSX, and Windows are all embedded in the sqlite-jdbc.jar...

```
org/sqlite/native/Linux/amd64/libsqlitejdbc.so
org/sqlite/native/Linux/i386/libsqlitejdbc.so
org/sqlite/native/Mac/i386/libsqlitejdbc.jnilib
org/sqlite/native/Mac/x86_64/libsqlitejdbc.jnilib
org/sqlite/native/Windows/amd64/sqlitejdbc.dll
org/sqlite/native/Windows/x86/sqlitejdbc.dll
```

My problem is, that while I'm running Linux, I am not on amd64 or i386.  The Raspberry Pi is ARM. Where can I get a sqlite-jdbc.jar with the ARM binaries embedded?

Answer (score 0):

A lib provided by someone who claims to have build it: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issue/79/compile-for-arm

Instructions for build https://pidome.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/java-goes-hard-on-the-raspberry-pi-so-does-pidome/

and
[Error opening connection SQLite on Raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665796/error-opening-connection-sqlite-on-raspberry-pi)

Comment: I saw these.  I was trying to avoid having to build it myself.  Is there any published version already put together?  I fear the reason that xerial doesn't provide it, is that there is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

@dacracot

I'm not sure if i'm prohibited by offering help this way but:

I have the library available when you would download the whole PiDome server package.

For convenience, and multiple requests i have added it as a separate download. The library has been compiled against the hard float abi and is currently using sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15.

The jar file contains the default supported platform libraries and has the arm support added.

It is available at: https://bitbucket.org/pidome/pidome-server/downloads